# FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 4 tables
StokCard table
StokGroup table
GroupFeature table and StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue table
All tables getting Primary Key from BaseModel
But I am getting this error

[Error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4eMM.png)

```
public class StokCard : BaseModel
{
        public string IPMKodu { get; set; }
        public int StokGroupId { get; set; }
        public StokGroup StokGroup { get; set; }
        ........................................ other properties
}

public class StokGroup:BaseModel
{
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public List<GroupFeature> GroupFeatures { get; set; }
        public List<StokCard> StokCards { get; set; }
}
public class GroupFeature : BaseModel
{
        public int StokGroupId { get; set; }
        public StokGroup StokGroup { get; set; }
        public List<StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue> StokCardAdditionalFeatureValues { get; set; }
}

public class StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue:BaseModel
{
        public int StokKartId { get; set; }
        public StokCard StokCard { get; set; }
        public int GroupFeatureId { get; set; }
        public GroupFeature GroupFeature { get; set; }
        public string FeatureValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This question can get a better answer at dba.stackexchange.com and instead of C# classes use your SQL table definitions.

Comment: What do you mean all tables get the PKs from BaseModel? Can you show BaseModel class?

Comment: public class BaseModel
    {
        [Key] 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
    }

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `StokCardAdditionalFeatureValue` we have at least two cascade paths:

Through `GroupFeater` property and then we have reference to `StokGroup`

Through `StokCard` and then through `StokGroup`

You need to verify and clean up your database design to not cause such cycles.